# Set two "local" options in an ngSelect

Tags: angularjs

Okay, so I'm populating a dropdown with values from a service:

```
<select ng-model="things.thing" id="thing" name="thing"
        ng-options="thing.id as thing.description for thing in things" >
    <option value="" selected>Select a thing</option>
</select>
```

With the json:

```
[ 
  {"id": 1, "description": "this is an option"},
  {"id": 2, "description": "second option right here"},
  {"id": 3, "description": "there are three even"},
  etc
]
```

This outputs the following:

[image: html page]

But my goal is to have an extra option "unknown thing" that, after being selected, activates another input field with an ng-show, where the user can specify their own thing. But when I add an extra `<option>` this gets ignored in the output?

```
<option value="0">Add new thing</option>
```

This is the output: 
[image: Snapshot from Firefox Inspector]

No extra option. Can I not do this? How would I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try repeating options instead of using ng-repeat in select

```
<select ng-model="selectedThing" >
  <option value="Select a thing">Select a thing</option>
  <option ng-repeat="($thing_index, thing) in things track by $thing_index" ng-value="thing.description">{{thing.description}}</option>
</select>
```

In controller:

```
   $scope.selectedThing = 'Select a thing'
   $scope.things = [ 
      {"id": 1, "description": "this is an option"},
      {"id": 2, "description": "second option right here"},
      {"id": 3, "description": "there are three even"}
    ]
```

Comment: This works! Event though this <select> is now the only one in my app that doesn't use ng-select... it still fixed the problem. Thanks!